# Different colors for different h1 titles in differents components with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to get different colors for different titles in different components with a React application.

I dispatched the css into two different css files but the h1 color which is applied is the same (the last value read) for both h1 titles.

```js
// App.js
import React from "react";
import ComponentOne from "./ComponentOne.component";
import ComponentTwo from "./ComponentTwo.component";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentOne />
      <ComponentTwo />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// ComponentOne.module.css
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```
// ComponentTwo.module.css
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

In each component I have the corresponding CSS import line:

```js
import "./ComponentOne.module.css";
```

Can you help me figuring out what is going wrong with my code please ?

The "module" naming convention I used for the CSS files is adapted from [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/), while the whole code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hawking-w35ez).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it only picks blue is because the browser does not care about what css is in what file, it will just read it all, and if there is already a style for a `h1` and then it finds a different style for a `h1` it will simply overwrite the previous style.

In your case the red color gets overwritten, and instead all the h1 become blue

This is why its very bad practice to just overwrite all instances of a specific element type. instead what you should do is wrap your code in a div/span with some id/class like this:

```
<div id="section1">
  <h1>i am blue</h1>
</div>

<div id="section2">
  <h1>i am red</h1>
</div>
```

and then instead of styling all the h1's everywhere on the page, you could style all the h1's that are contained in an element with some id. you can do that like this

```
#section1 > h1 {
  color: blue;
}

#section2 > h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue in that when you use `css module` you need to import those `classes` and need to use it there. You can't use it on `tag` or `elements`. For that you need to use `styled-component` or any similar library.

IN your case you need to like this:

```
<div>
        <h1 className={styles.heading}>Component One</h1>
      </div>
```

where `heading` is your class name.

Full code:

1. **ComponentOne.component.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "./ComponentOne.module.css";

export default class ComponentOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className={styles.heading}>Component One</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ComponentOne.module.css**

```
.heading {
  color: red;
}
```

2. **ComponentTwo.component.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "./ComponentTwo.module.css";

export default class ComponentTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className={styles.heading}>Component Two</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ComponentTwo.module.css**

```
.heading {
  color: red;
}
```

Code and demo can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-dream-2ocmf?file=/src/ComponentOne.component.js

Comment: That is actually a really nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that without an extra pre-processor JavaScript won't scope your CSS files to specific components. It will just include both files to the app CSS output. And because the second and last loaded module was setting the colour to blue, it overrides the first one.

You will need to identify both components by a class or an ID so you can apply the styles conditionally.

Comment: its not just the pre-processor if you would include the css files manually using <link> it would still be over writing the styles

Comment: @Luke_ I use [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) and there the pre-processor attaches styles to components using unique component-specific IDs and classes. So theoretically it is possible.

Comment: ohhh u said without an extra pre-processor...i misunderstood it as with a extra pre-processor (as in, you think its caused by some reactjs pre-processor). im sorry, just ignore me... have a nice day stanger! : )

Comment: This solution sounds great. I tried to add [Sass pre-processor](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-johnson-2hitf) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I honestly think you should go with @ShubhamVerma's solution. It's simple, elegant and self-explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

Use className instead. Since `<componentTwo />` gets rendered least it's styling will dominate.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

add in-line styling for example:

```
<div>
    <h1 style={{color:"red"}}>Component Two</h1>
</div>
```

or you can also programatically change the styling

```
 render() {
    var color = "blue";
    var foo = "bar"
    if(foo == "bar"){
      color="red"
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={{color:color}}>Component Two</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
```